# getting error information on cfgrid - cfdebug

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I'm using CF9

When editing a field which updates information on a db in a cfgrid, I get this error:

"Error invoking CFC /assetMgmt/assetdata.cfc : Error Executing Database Query. [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information]".

adding ?cfdebug to the end of the url and hitting enter opens the menu to search for items to populate the grid, so the cfdebug parameter gets removed once the grid has been populated (because of hitting the search button).

I guess I need some way to enable this cfdebug mode without having to navigate to the page, since it removes the cfgrid.  Sorry if that sounds confusing

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you on? If you're on CF8 I think this covers your issue http://forums.adobe.com/message/43597

Comment: If Matt's link doesn't slove the problem, do you have other url variables?  then you'd need to add &cfdebug.

Comment: @Matt Busche apologies, I'm on CF9

Comment: @Travis no, no other url vars

Comment: have you: Select the Enable Ajax Debug Log Window option on the ColdFusion Administrator > Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings page. To view exception messages in the logging window, you must select the Enable Robust Exception Information option on the Debug Output Settings page.
Make sure that the IP address of the system where you will be doing the debugging is included on the ColdFusion Administrator > Debugging & Logging > Debugging IP List page of the ColdFusion Administrator. By default this list includes only 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Travis, thank you for your response.  I was able to get the logging window to come up, but the same issue is occurring: when the search button is pressed the logging window disappears.  Is there a way to make the logging window persist during the page reload?

I've uploaded a screenshot to imgur to illustrate: http://imgur.com/Hig4SDO.  When the search button is pressed, since it's a self-posting form, the logging window disappears

Comment: Am I missing something?  I don't see a grid.  cfdebug is supposed to help troubleshoot ajax calls but I see a standard form here for which you can simply output anything you want during the return request.  you could also use your browser developer tools' response tab to see what's going on too instead of relying on cfdebug.

Comment: When the search button is pressed on the form I screenshotted, the cfgrid appears because the form is self-posting.  Thus if I have the page's name in the address bar with ?cfdebug, upon hitting the search button the address bar is reset, removing ?cfdebug.  Because of that, I can't log what's happening when I try to update a cell in the cfgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my advice: Use chrome or Safari. Open the developer tools and look at the console.  Make sure that xmlhttprequests are being logged.

Now access the page with the issue.  You will see the error logged (likely a 500 error) in the console along with the URL that was requested.  Right click on the url and open in a new tab.  This will rerun the request and output the result directly in the browser so you can see the error being thrown.  Fix the error and you should be good to go.

If you need any more assistance please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found that giving a `sql` column an `alias` with a space in it caused an issue in `ext-all.js` with `cfgrid`.  To fix this, I replaced the spaces with non breaking spaces (`&nbsp`) and it solved the issue.